# Visual Editor is blank - 404 for plugin js

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor

My client's visual editor is not working. I'm seeing a ton of JS errors in the console. All 404 errors for plugin files related to tiny_mce. Here's a couple:

```
http://www.livebeautifull.com/wp-content/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/assets/datepicker/datepicker.css?ver=4.3 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.livebeautifull.com/wp-content/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-cust…-kit-api/assets/js/tiny_mce/plugins/charmap/plugin.js?wp-mce-4203-20150730 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) tinymce.min.js?ver=4203-20150730:4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated to the latest version of the WCK - Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Creator plugin?

The issue is with the WCK - Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Creator plugin and you should probably seek direct assistance from them.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/

When I checked the plugins code (vers. 1.1.5) I can see in the wck-fep.php the reference to datepicker.css which may be causing the 404 error since it does not exist:

```
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');      
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', plugins_url( '', dirname(__FILE__) ).'/assets/datepicker/datepicker.css');
```

They state in the Changelog that they fixed the issue with the 404 reporting for the datepicker.css in vers 1.1.0, but I still see code within the wck-fep.php file as mentioned above.

The changelog also states that in version 1.0.9 they changed from the tinymce to ckeditor plugin.

= 1.0.9 =
* Replaced wysiwyg editor from **tinymce** to **ckeditor** to fix compatibility issues with WordPress 3.9

```
    // wysiwyg              
    wp_register_script( 'wck-ckeditor', plugins_url( '', dirname(__FILE__) ).'/assets/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js', array(), '1.0', true );
```

Not certain why you're still showing it still trying to access tinymce unless you're using an older version of the plugin. I can not find any reference to it in the current version of the plugin.